# Anyone know of a flow chart or list of common/useful consequences of Maxwell's equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

I just recently started to appreciate the Maxwell equations. I had never really take the time to study them but I feel like I'm finally more familiar with them. I've noticed that it seems like a lot of basic electrostatic laws such as Coulomb's law can be derived from them and vice versa.  I'd like to try some of these derivations that is, show that other laws can be derived from Maxwell's equations. I think this would be easiest to do if I had a list of some of the most common/useful theories that can be derived from his equations.

Does anyone know of a flow chart or a list that nicely summarizes common / useful theories that can be deduced from Maxwell's equations (eg Coulomb's law)?

Comment: The question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: Sorry, is that not allowed? I wasn't necessarily asking people to answer with a list but a link to one. But if that's not allowed either then I won't ask this type in the future.